# How to receive data from Xbee in AT mode on Arduino Nano

Tags: serial, arduino-nano, xbee

I need to print data on the Arduino serial monitor received from the Xbee in AT mode. I have searched on most forums and have not found anything on how to do this.

I have my Xbee tx connected to Arduino nano Rx and rx connected to tx.

Answer (score 1):

You connected the Xbee to the single hardware serial interface that the Nano has. Is is also used by the USB to Serial chip, which connects to the Serial Monitor. So what you are sending to the Xbee is also sent to the Serial Monitor. What the Xbee sends is only sent to the Arduino (since the Xbee TX pin is connected to RX of Arduino and also TX of the Arduino's USB to Serial chip).

But you can separate then by using a `SoftwareSerial` interface on any other pins of your liking. Then you can connect the Xbee to it. Then forward the output of the `SoftwareSerial` interface to the `Serial` interface. To see how this works have a look the [first example of the `SoftwareSerial` library](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/libraries/SoftwareSerial/examples/SoftwareSerialExample/SoftwareSerialExample.ino). It's basically checking both interfaces, reads available data from one interface and writes it to the other (note the `write()` in contrast to `print()` since when forwarding you don't want to interpret the data again to another format like `print()` does).

Also there are plenty examples and tutorials about `SoftwareSerial` on the web. An important restriction is that only one `SoftwareSerial` interface can listen to data at any time. The Hardware `Serial` interface doesn't have such a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try this. You said that only one Software Serial can listen to data at once. Does this mean that I would not be able to connect a GPS module to a software serial interface on different pins as well as the Xbee module? How would I solve this problem?

Comment: When you are interfacing a module, which only will send data, when you ask for it, you can implement time sharing. So listen to one interface, asking the corresponding module for info and reading it. Then listen on the other interface, asking that module for info and reading it. Rinse and repeat. Though this only works if you cannot miss data from one module while you are reading the other. If you would miss data, you can change to a microcontroller with more Hardware Serial interfaces, like the Arduino Mega.

Comment: Ok thank you this makes sense.

Comment: How do I add the SoftwareSerial Library? It does not seem to come up in the Library Manager?

Comment: Because its already part of the Arduino Core. You don't need to install it. You can use it directly with the Arduino IDE.